# Popstate back button functionality slow in Chrome and IE(firefox is fine)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, html5-history

I managed to setup a working example of using HTML5 History API. It works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome and IE11, every new press of the back or forward buttons makes page loading time much slower.

After 4 or 5 presses(going back and forth between two pages) it gets really slow.

Guess it is maybe down to on how I use AJAX to load the content, but why is it working nicely for the first few transitions between pages.

Here is a working link:
http://madebym.me/playground/AJAX-transitions/

And here is the code snippet that makes it all work:

```
loadContent = function () {
$.ajax({
url: pageUrl, success: function (data) {
        $('#main-content').html(data);
    }
});

if (pageUrl != window.location) {
    window.history.pushState({ path: pageUrl }, '', pageUrl);
}

}

$(window).on('popstate', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: location.pathname, success: function (data) {
            $('#main-content').html(data);
        }
    });
});


$('a').on('click', function () {
pageUrl = $(this).attr('href');
loadContent();
return false;

});
```